# Move facebook likes from one url to another

Tags: facebook

Over time I have built up a number of facebook likes on page = http://www.andy-howard.com/verticalAndHorizontalAlignment/index.html

But I need to convert this page to a php script (to be content manageable). Most likely it will be = http://www.andy-howard.com/code-help.php?id=143

Is there a way I can transfer my existing facebook likes to the new url?

Comment: Can't you just keep the content at the old URL? The old one is significantly better than the new one, as it actually says what the content is. You can use rewrite rules if you want to do an "internal" redirect to a new system.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t transfer likes from one URL to another.

Only thing you can do, is make Facebook “believe” that the URL is still the old one – by setting the `og:url` meta tag in your *new* pages to the *old* URLs.

Facebook will use that value as the canoncial URL to identify this Open Graph object and to fetch the Open Graph information from, so you will have to see to it that those old URLs are

- still available for the FB scraper to visit,
- give it the OG info it is looking for, and
- that “normal” visitors are redirected to the new URL, should Facebook link them to the old one

How to detect that the FB scraper is requesting your page, is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to transfer likes from one url to another. Facebook like plugin is designed so that you can be on one page while actually liking completely other page (i.e. url). If that likes really matter, you can save the old url in database for each content and continue collecting likes for that url and just redirect visitors from that url to the new one.